# How to move changes from previous branch of the current branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have Branch A that has some changes and Branch B that has changes too, but I want to the changes of branch A do not appear in branch B.

My commits look something like this:-

```
commit 3 - branch B
commit 2 - branch A
commit 1 - branch A
master
```

I want commit 3 - branch B to after master or to remove the changes made in branch A from branch B, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Branch you wanted get the uncommited changes from:

```
git stash
```

then go to branch you wanted to apply the changes

```
git checkout {branch-name}
git stash apply
```

Comment: Is possible to remove changes of branch A from branch B after I pushed the code?

Comment: yes, you can uncommit the changes  git reset --soft HEAD^{commit id}